# Can I send an operator as parameter to a function?

Tags: c++

For example I can write in c:

```
int sum(int a, int b);
void print(int a, int b, int (*f)(int, int));
```

The question is can I send an operator?

```
print(12, 13, sum);
// print(12, 13, operator +); compilation error
```

Comment: see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/992320/can-operators-be-used-as-functions-c/

Answer (score 12):

Unfortunately, that’s not possible. There are wrappers for some common operators in the C++ standard library, in the `functional` header, e.g. [`std::plus<T>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/plus). It won’t work with your code though, since your `print` function requires a specific function parameter which `plus<int>` isn’t.

Instead of that, try passing a template argument, that works much better:

```
template <typename BinaryFunction>
void print(int a, int b, BinaryFunction f);

print(12, 13, std::plus<int>());
```

Comment: In the function signature, you should remove int before BinaryFunction.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it's possible in general, but there's no `int operator+(int, int)`. `int+int` happens to be a built-in expression. It would work for `std::string::operator+`